# Set boolean method always outputting true?

Tags: java, set

I'm having a difficult time trying to figure out why method is working incorrectly.

My method `addtoHash()` is always returning true and for some reason it also only looks at the first value before returning true.

Sorry if this is kinda confusing, my code should better explain it!

Originally my code was like this, and it definitely worked:

```
  public void addtoHash(Set reserve, int value)
    {
        if(value > 0 && value < 10)
        {
            reserve.add(value)
        }
    }

public boolean squareCheck(int[][][] board, int index)
{
    Set<Integer> reserve = new HashSet<>();

    for(int r = 0; r < board[0].length; r++)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < board[0].length; c++)
        { 
            addtoHash(reserve,board[index][r][c]);
            if(r == 2 && c == 2 && reserve.size() < 9)
            {
              System.out.println("Error in grid " + index);
              return false;
            }


        }
    }
    return true;

}
```

Since I wanted to make it more useful I changed addtoHash() to return a boolean instead:

```
public boolean addtoHash(Set reserve, int value)
{
    if(value > 0 && value < 10)
    {
        return reserve.add(value) == true;
    }

    return false;
}
public boolean squareCheck(int[][][] board, int index)
{
    Set<Integer> reserve = new HashSet<>();

    for(int r = 0; r < board[0].length; r++)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < board[0].length; c++)
        { 
            if(!addtoHash(reserve,board[index][r][c]))
                System.out.println("Error at " + index+r+c);
                    return false;
        }
    }
    return true;

}
```

Checking if this works:

```
int[][][] solved = {{{5,3,2},{6,7,2},{1,9,8}}, //My new code doesn't find the duplicate and return false here, despite my previous code having done so!
                    {{6,7,8},{1,9,5},{3,4,2}},
                    {{9,1,2},{3,4,8},{5,6,7}},
                    {{8,5,9},{4,2,6},{7,1,3}},
                    {{7,6,1},{8,5,3},{9,2,4}},
                    {{4,2,3},{7,9,1},{8,5,6}},
                    {{9,6,1},{2,8,7},{3,4,5}},
                    {{5,3,7},{4,1,9},{2,8,6}},
                    {{2,8,4},{6,3,5},{1,7,9}}}; 
validCheck checker = new validCheck();
checker.squareCheck(solved,0);
```

However after running it several times and using `System.out.println()`, I found that it always returned `true`; after printing out the Set I found that it only checked the first value, so the output would be `[5] true`.

Is there something wrong with my logic and that's why it's always returning true, or is there something else that I'm missing?

Comment: The answer you've got is correct. In addition, both of`r` and `c`, for loop variables, iterate until `board[0].length`. It seems wrong to me since `r` and `c` are not in the same dimension of array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `return false` here is unconditionally executed:

> ```
>         if(!addtoHash(reserve,board[index][r][c]))
>             System.out.println("Error at " + index+r+c);
>                 return false;
> ```

Because that code is equivalent to this:

```
        if(!addtoHash(reserve,board[index][r][c])) {
            System.out.println("Error at " + index+r+c);
        }
        return false;
```

You need this:

```
        if (!addtoHash(reserve, board[index][r][c])) {
            System.out.println("Error at " + index + r + c);
            return false;
        }
```

What you did is a very common mistake.
For that it's recommend to always use braces with `if` statements,
that way it would be trivial to spot this kind of mistake.

---

Btw, you can simplify `addToHash` to this:

```
public boolean addtoHash(Set<Integer> reserve, int value) {
    return 0 < value && value < 10 && reserve.add(value);
}
```